# OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3075200,512] and type float on : why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

[image: This is the picture using command gpustat -i]

[image: And This is the picture using method device_lib.list_local_devices]
[image: My model]

I am experimenting by creating a grayscale image to use the CNN model(using keras).
I have to experiment with the image size of 512*512, but I get a memory overflow error.
I can't reduce the image size anymore, and if I look at gpustat, it's 32GB, but I don't know why the memory error pops up. I am not sure where and how to find and increase the allocable gpu memory.

Here are the attempts I have made so far.

1.Reducing the number of neurons in a layer
2. Using a smaller batch size (current batch size 5)
3. Increase Maxpooling size to use
4. Increase stride size
5. Dropout
6. config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
7. config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction
8. strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
9. mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/GPU:0", "/XLA_GPU:1"])

I've tried all of the above, but it doesn't work. If you know how to fix, please answer.
You cannot reduce the image size. (This is the purpose of my experiment)
And it says that the GPU memory is 32GB, but if you let me know why the error occurs when it is not 32GB, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is the title a typo?  Where does the 3075200 come from?

Comment: @FrankYellin This is just typing the error message. The 3075200 is from my model :) Since it is running on a separate server, I cannot copy and paste it, so I will upload it as a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. Stop using `Flatten` and change it to `GlobalAveragePooling2D` or `GlobalMaxPooling2D`.

Long answer. What you're trying is use `64*64*800` as input size of a Fully connected layer which is wayyyy too big. Modern CNN models are all no longer use `Flatten` and replace it with `GlobalAveragePooling2D` as it also reserve variable size capability of CNN.

Comment: As I said, I reduced it from 800 to 624, and when I used GlobalAveragePooling, it was unfortunate when it tried to work. First of all, it seems appropriate to reduce the size of the connection layer. Could you please let me know if you know what determines this size?

Comment: I normally use standard size like 224*224 for ResNet or 299*299 for inception

Comment: If your data is normal image and you just want to classify it then I'd suggest use pre-made model like ResNet instead

Comment: 800*800 is not that big as input size, normally I use bigger than that in object detection task. Your architecture is what need to change

Comment: Also `batch size`, 800*800 is not big if you feed 1-2 images but maybe 4 is biggest a GPU could hold in training

Comment: Thank you. I simply wanted to experiment with the 512 size, so I thought I had to increase the size of the connection layer to fit. First, we are experimenting with reducing the size of the layers. Let's experiment with the size you advised. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: The 512 kernel on the first layer is also too much. Normally at that stage it would be 64 or 32. And get wider (more kernel) after each downsampling.

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/bc89834ed36935ab4a4994446e34ff81c0d8e1b7/keras_applications/vgg16.py#L108